# How to define a Column for buttons in FXML (JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, fxml

I know that it is possible to create a column in TableView filled with buttons [thanks to jewelsea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16360323/javafx-table-how-to-add-components/16366638#16366638).

But I want to know if it's possible to define it **directly in the FXML**.

As an example, with other types one do:

**Class Person**:

```java
private final SimpleStringProperty birthDate = new SimpleStringProperty("");
```

Then in the FXML:

```xml
    <TableView fx:id="table" layoutY="50.0" prefHeight="350.0" prefWidth="600.0">
      <columns>
        <TableColumn prefWidth="79.5" text="date of birth">
            <cellValueFactory>
               <PropertyValueFactory property="birthDate" />
            </cellValueFactory>
        </TableColumn>
      </columns>
    </TableView>
```

**And one can add this element with**:

```java
@FXML private TableView<Person> table;
//...
table.getItems().add("12/02/1452");
```

How to achieve the same with Buttons?

Comment: Well it's not possible in Scene Builder.

Comment: I think this isn't possible.
You have to set the Cell Factory over your Code.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible you have init it with code

```
class ButtonListCell extends ListCell<MyObject> {
    @Override
    public void updateItem(MyObject obj, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(obj, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            setText(obj.toString());

            Button butt = new Button();
            butt.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    System.out.println("clicked");
                }                            
            });
            setGraphic(butt);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
listview.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<MyObject>, ListCell>() {
    @Override
    public ListCell call(ListView<MyObject> param) {
        return new ButtonListCell();
    }

});
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible to add buttons to table column in FXML since cell factory is required.

You can do it with Java code as you jewelsea did.