# JavaFX 8 TableView with ToggleButton to Show/Hide Password

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am trying to create a TableView with a Button for each row to show/hide the password for that particular row. I have been using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16360323/javafx-table-how-to-add-components?rq=1) question in order to figure it out but I am truly stumped now. So my question is how can I get this to work? What am I doing wrong?

Here is what I've got so far.

Person.java

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class Person {
    private final SimpleStringProperty name;
    private final SimpleStringProperty password;
    private final SimpleStringProperty maskedPassword;

    public Person(String n, String p) {
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(n);
        this.password = new SimpleStringProperty(p);
        this.maskedPassword = new SimpleStringProperty(maskPass(p));
    }

    private String maskPass(String password) {
        String output = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++) {
            output += "\u2022";
        }
        return output;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name.get();
    }

    public void setName(String n) {
        this.name.set(n);
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password.get();
    }

    public void setPassword(String p) {
        this.password.set(p);
        this.maskedPassword.set(maskPass(p));
    }

    public String getMaskedPassword() {
        return this.maskedPassword.get();
    }
}
```

and Main.java

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class Main extends Application{

    private final TableView<Person> table = new TableView<Person>();
    private final ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new Person("Moses Kiptanui", "pas$w0rd"),
                new Person("Bob Geldof", "hunter2"),
                new Person("Steve Finnan", "skadjhf"),
                new Person("Don Bradman", "CRICKET!"),
                new Person("Fetty Wap", "seventeen38")
            );

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setTitle("Table Experiment");

        TableColumn<Person, String> nameCol = new TableColumn<Person, String>("Name");
        nameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        nameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("name"));

        TableColumn<Person, String> passwordCol = new TableColumn<Person, String>("Password");
        passwordCol.setMinWidth(100);
        passwordCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("maskedPassword"));

        TableColumn<Person, Person> btnCol = new TableColumn<Person, Person>("Show/Hide");
        btnCol.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Person, Person>, TableCell<Person, Person>>() {
            @Override
            public TableCell<Person, Person> call(TableColumn<Person, Person> btnCol) {
                return new TableCell<Person, Person>() {
                    final ToggleButton btn = new ToggleButton("Show");
                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(final Person person, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(person, empty);
                        if(person != null) {
                            if(btn.isSelected()) {
                                btn.setText("Hide");
                            } else {
                                btn.setText("Show");
                            }
                            setGraphic(btn);
                            btn.setOnAction(e -> {
                                if(btn.isSelected()) {
                                    passwordCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("password"));
                                } else {
                                    passwordCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("maskedPassword"));
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        });

        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll(nameCol, passwordCol, btnCol);
        VBox vb = new VBox(table);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(vb));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

And here is what it looks like at the moment. I have actually had it so the buttons show, but they showed in every row, not just the ones where the person != null. When I did have them showing they did not work though.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/gAndrGS.jpg]

Comment: thats nice .... was there a question somewhere in-between all of these weird approaches?

Comment: Yes - What am I doing wrong? How can I get this to work?

Comment: Did you try to see if person is really null? Did you try to put a log in your if-else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how I would approach this:

1. I don't think the masked password, or indeed whether or not the password should be masked, should be part of your `Person` class. That is not an intrinsic part of the data, it's part of the view of the data.
2. The `TableColumn` showing the password needs to use a custom cell factory, that either displays the actual password, or the masked password, depending on whether or not the toggle button is pressed.
3. You can't access the toggle buttons directly, as they are part of the virtualized cells, so you need some other data that tracks which passwords are shown and which are hidden. One way (the simplest, I think), is just to use an `ObservableSet` containing the items for which the password is shown.

Now you need to make sure the toggle state matches the observable set, so you need a listener with the toggle button that updates the observable set, and a listener with the observable set that updates the toggle button. The cell factory for the password column must also observe the `ObservableSet` and update the text in that column accordingly.

Here's a SSCCE:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableSet;
import javafx.collections.SetChangeListener.Change;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ShowHidePasswordExample extends Application {

    private static final Random RNG = new Random();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        TableView<User> userTable = new TableView<>();

        // standard column stuff:
        TableColumn<User, String> userNameCol = new TableColumn<>("User Name");
        userNameCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().userNameProperty());

        TableColumn<User, String> passwordCol = new TableColumn<>("Password");
        passwordCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().passwordProperty());

        // which passwords are shown:
        ObservableSet<User> usersWithShownPasswords = FXCollections.observableSet();

        // cell factory for password column. Cells must show either the
        // real or masked password, and may 
        // need to update if usersWithShownPasswords changes:

        passwordCol.setCellFactory(c -> {

            // plain old cell:
            TableCell<User, String> cell = new TableCell<>();

            // if the cell is reused for an item from a different row, update it:
            cell.indexProperty().addListener((obs, oldIndex, newIndex) -> 
                updateCell(usersWithShownPasswords, cell));

            // if the password changes, update:

            cell.itemProperty().addListener((obs, oldItem, newItem) -> 
                updateCell(usersWithShownPasswords, cell));

            // if the set of users with shown password changes, update the cell:
            usersWithShownPasswords.addListener((Change<? extends User> change) ->
                updateCell(usersWithShownPasswords, cell));

            return cell ;
        });

        // column with show/hide buttons:
        TableColumn<User, User> showHidePasswordCol = new TableColumn<>("Show/Hide password");

        // just use whole row (User) as data for cells in this column:
        showHidePasswordCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(cellData.getValue()));

        // cell factory for toggle buttons:
        showHidePasswordCol.setCellFactory(c -> new TableCell<User, User>() {

            // create toggle button once for cell:
            private final ToggleButton button = new ToggleButton();

            // anonymous constructor:
            {
                // update toggle button state if usersWithShownPasswords changes:
                usersWithShownPasswords.addListener((Change<? extends User> change) -> {
                    button.setSelected(usersWithShownPasswords.contains(getItem()));
                });

                // update usersWithShownPasswords if toggle selection changes:
                button.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected) -> {
                    if (isNowSelected) {
                        usersWithShownPasswords.add(getItem());
                    } else {
                        usersWithShownPasswords.remove(getItem());
                    }
                });

                // keep text "Show" or "Hide" appropriately:
                button.textProperty().bind(Bindings.when(button.selectedProperty()).then("Hide").otherwise("Show"));
                setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            }

            // Just update graphic as needed:

            @Override
            public void updateItem(User item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (empty) {
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    button.setSelected(usersWithShownPasswords.contains(item));
                    setGraphic(button);
                }
            }
        });

        userTable.getColumns().addAll(Arrays.asList(userNameCol, passwordCol, showHidePasswordCol));

        userTable.getItems().addAll(createData());

        Scene scene = new Scene(new BorderPane(userTable), 800, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    private void updateCell(ObservableSet<User> usersWithShownPasswords,
            TableCell<User, String> cell) {
        int index = cell.getIndex();
        TableView<User> table = cell.getTableView();
        if (index < 0 || index >= table.getItems().size()) {
            cell.setText("");
        } else {
            User user = table.getItems().get(index);
            if (usersWithShownPasswords.contains(user)) {
                cell.setText(user.getPassword()) ;
            } else {
                cell.setText(mask(user.getPassword()));
            }
        }
    }

    private String mask(String text) {
        char[] chars = new char[text.length()];
        Arrays.fill(chars, '*');
        return new String(chars);
    }

    private List<User> createData() {
        return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100)
                .mapToObj(i -> new User("User "+i, randomPassword()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private String randomPassword() {
        int pwSize = 6 + RNG.nextInt(5);
        char[] chars = new char[pwSize];
        for (int i = 0 ; i < chars.length; i++) {
            chars[i] = (char)('a'+RNG.nextInt(26));
        }
        return new String(chars);
    }

    public static class User {
        private final StringProperty userName = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final StringProperty password = new SimpleStringProperty();

        public User(String userName, String password) {
            setUserName(userName);
            setPassword(password);
        }

        public final StringProperty userNameProperty() {
            return this.userName;
        }

        public final java.lang.String getUserName() {
            return this.userNameProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setUserName(final java.lang.String userName) {
            this.userNameProperty().set(userName);
        }

        public final StringProperty passwordProperty() {
            return this.password;
        }

        public final java.lang.String getPassword() {
            return this.passwordProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setPassword(final java.lang.String password) {
            this.passwordProperty().set(password);
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```